# ERROR_STATE'. (35) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: python, hive, pyodbc

Here is some python code which is being executed against a HIVE database

```
pyodbc.autocommit = True
con = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MyCon", autocommit=True)
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("select name, surname from foo f inner join bar b on f.id = b.id")
```

Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (35) Error from 
Hive: error code: '0' error message: 'ExecuteStatement finished with operation 
state: ERROR_STATE'. (35) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. when creating the ODBC connection use the user hdfs. I had read a tutorial and was using the user hue.

this caused the problem.